# ssh-copy-id does not copy to custom 'AuthorizedKeysFile' specified in sshd_config

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd, authorized-keys

I have a modified location for my user's authorized_keys including those of root's away from `/<user>/.ssh` to `/abc/%u`.

```
[root@server]# grep AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  /abc/%u
```

But ssh-copy-id seems to not use that information from remote server and instead always copies to ".ssh/authorized_keys" as suggested below in the snapshot. Any way to explicitly ask ssh-copy-id to add the key to proper location pointed `/abc/%u` to by AuthorizedKeysFile on server?

```
root@client# ssh-copy-id  root@server
Password: ********
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'root@server'", and check in:

  .ssh/authorized_keys

to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.

root@client#
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the user's config you are running under using $HOME/.ssh/config, and set the IdentityFile option. Nixcraft has some good examples up at [http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I don't have control over the server configuration. I only have info about the customization done to global sshd_config file and I need to use the path provided there "AuthorizedKeysFile  /abc/%u". The only solution I can think of is to generate ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and copy it over to /abc/<user>

Comment: Or you could just symbolically link it with ln -s ~/.ssh/authorized_keys /some/other/location. I am perplexed because moving the files around won't really make things any safer, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Faern new users on the local can create a authorized_keys file which allows users to grant keys remote access, moving these files to a restricted location is a layer of control of which profiles can grant keys access. depending on your structure (eg `/abc/%u`) it is also easier to setup, compare, auditing and updates manually. there are negatives like auth files left behind for removed profiles but may not be an issue depending on your use case.  guess it is more about control than safety